# didUpdateToLocations: never ending?

Tags: ios6, core-location

Based on another SO question, I've implemented the `didUpdateLocations:` method as follows:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    // Get the latest location found
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (locationAge > 5.0) return;
    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;

    if (_bestEffort == nil || _bestEffort.horizontalAccuracy >= location.horizontalAccuracy) {
        _bestEffort = location;

        // Let the delegate know
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(location:didUpdateLocationTo:)]) {
            [self.delegate location:self didUpdateLocationTo:location];
        }

        if (location.horizontalAccuracy <= _locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {
            // Great, we've found our final location so stop searching!
            [self stopTrackingLocation];

            // Let our delegate know we've finished our work
            if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(location:didFinishTrackingLocationWithFinalLocation:)]) {
                [self.delegate location:self didFinishTrackingLocationWithFinalLocation:location];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything makes sense with this code, except that I can't seem to make it work correctly. When I step through the code, I find that

- locationAge is less than 5, which is good
- locations horizontalAccuracy is less than 0 which is good
- bestEfforts horizontal accuracy is the same as the locations horizontal accuracy, so it never enters that condition
- Even if it did, it would never call the `stopTrackingLocation` method, as the locations horizontalAccuracy can never be < 0 (second if statement) however, my location managers desired accuracy is -2 (best for navigation), so it never actually leaves this method.

What am I doing wrong, or how should I change this to work correctly?

Comment: horizontalAccuracy less than 0 means the location is invalid.

Comment: Why is your desired accuracy `-2`?  It should be a positive value, like 50 or 100, depending on how much accuracy (in meters) that you need?

Comment: That's what I thought, but that's just what I'm getting. I'm passing in `kCLLoationAccuracyBestForNavigation` and getting -2, and `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` gives -1. I changed it to 10 meters and it seems fine, but I still don't understand why I'm getting -1/-2 for the other two?

Comment: The -1 and -2 are just constants that signal to the CLLocationManager what you want.

Comment: The horizontalAccuracy in the reported location has a separate meaning.  It will be -1 when the location is invalid, that's normal, it make take many seconds before you get a good location depending on how clear of a view to the sky the device has.

Comment: It's currently running in the simulator though, so should be almost instant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get a location that has a horizontalAccuracy less than your desiredAccuracy.

```
if (location.horizontalAccuracy <= _locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {
```

However, the constants `kCLLoationAccuracyBestForNavigation` and `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` are not real values, they are -2 and -1 respectively.

The question is what accuracy do you really **need** for your purposes?  That is the value you should check for.  For test purposes, use 100 meters.  This will mean that you probably have a location using GPS, not just WiFi or Cellular.

```
if (location.horizontalAccuracy <= 100) {
```

The actual horizontalAccuracy will never be less that 5 meters with an iPhone 5.  It can be 10 or 20 or 50 depending on how many satellites are visible and their geometry.  It can also be -1 if the system cannot get a fix at all.  That is what this line is for, to ignore those invalid locations:

```
    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;
```

**EDIT:** 

The constants `kCLLoationAccuracyBestForNavigation` and `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` should only be used when you configure the `desiredAccuracy` property on the CLLocationManager object.  That `desiredAccuracy` setting configures the Core Location hardware to enable GPS, GLONASS, etc, to *try* to meet your desired accuracy (it doesn't guarantee it will be met).

The `desiredAccuracy` is **not** a value you should be using in your delegate method, it is only there to configure the CLLocationManager.

Comment: I understand what the code is doing and why it's never returning. I just couldn't quite figure out why the navigation and best accuracy values were -1 and -2, and I couldn't find any example where they were being used in this way. I've dropped the code to the nearest 10 meters as it's not overly important that it's pinpoint accurate, but I do want to be able to retrieve an address (accurately) from the users location as it will be for navigational purposes

Comment: I added more to my answer above to explain that you still want to use those constants but only when setting `desiredAccuracy` property.